# The fraction field of $S/q$ is a finite extension field of the fraction field of $R/p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let  $\varphi:R\to S$ be a map of rings, $p\in \text{Spec}\ R$ and $q\in \text{Spec}\ S$ such that $\varphi^{−1}(q)=p$. Then, is it true that  the fraction field of $S/q$  is a finite extension field of the fraction field of $R/p$?

I am totally confused by this question. A morphism between rings induces a morphism between their spectra. But, what is the significance of the condition $\varphi^{-1}(q)=p$ in the determination of whether the fraction field of $S/q$ is a finite extension of the fraction of $R/p$? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: That condition means the kernel of $R \to S \to S/p$ is $q$. Anyway, why not just look at an infinite extension of fields such as $\mathbf Q \hookrightarrow \mathbf R$?

Comment: @KCd so the claim is false right

Comment: $R/p$ is a subring (both integral domains) of $S/q$ ($\varphi$ is a map $R/p\to S/q$ and its kernel is contained in $p$). If $\varphi$ is a finite map then the fraction fields are finite extensions. Otherwise we can't say too much.